# How to Enable an External USB Hard Drive with Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, external-hard-drive

I'm trying to install a new LaCie Hard Disk design by Neil Poulton 1TB USB 2.0.

GParted reports

```
/dev/sda1 (with exclamation mark and key sign) ntfs 1 KiB
unallocated 320 MiB
/dev/sda2 hfs+ 2.84 MiB
unallocated 931.2 GiB
```

When trying to create a partition with Disk Utility it says

```
Daemon is inhibited
```

It seems I can't create the partition that way. Can you recommend how I can proceed?
Thank you

Comment: Oh, Palimsest. You may want to specify that, as Disk Utility is something from OS X.

Comment: hfs+ has little support on ubuntu/linux in general as of yet...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I now have managed to format and partition the drive to 1 partition NTFS trying to run a benchmark test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening GPartEd and reformat to one partition and something a bit more easy to use (e.g. nfts, xFAT, FATx.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears to work now after removed and created partitions with GUID partition tables. GParted reports just 1 partition ntfs with key and red exclamation mark 931.51 GiB and I can copy data and also could connect it both to a laptop and another computer both running Linux (Ubuntu). But I can't run the benchmark since then it says :Daemon is inhibited

Comment: That good to hear